# How to create a big size file in windows with out using any extra tools?

Tags: windows, pdf

I am trying to create a 250 mb of valid file in pdf or any other format. I tried with ms word and created around 3k pages with images in it, but still it was of the size of 10 mb only.

any ideas or suggestions ? I have proper pdf adobe version which can create pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this... use adobe acrobat to create the pdf.. add the high end images and create a PDF with the  option to preserve image original quality.